# Slow MySQL select query and crash in C# WPF

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, database

I made a c# app that in a part of this,there is a datagrid bound to datatable, and the datatable will be filled from MySQL database, using a select query in a method.

I have two problems:
1) when I load a table in first time, its take about 8 second(just 6 rows) and next time just less than 2 seconds.why first query is so slow?

2) I made a testy table with 10000 rows, tried to load it but the app stopped!
   I made a new WPF project and used same code for getting rows from MySQL,it worked quite well and datagrid showed data after 10 seconds.
I used task to make select query method asynchronous,tried it in first project,but nothing changed!

For second problem that I raised,it may relate to my PC, I'm using:

> Pentium dual core CPU,2.7 GHz and 2.69 GHz
>   4 GB RAM,Windows 10,64
>   bit

But if this is from my PC, so the new project must face to this problem too and crash,but it didn't happen! and I used DatabaseBrowser application too, there was no problem with this.

This is my code, MainWindow calls "SelectQuery" method in MySQL class that I made:

```
public MySqlConnection connection()
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default.Reload();
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.con);   // con is string defined in properties, Settings.settings
        return conn;
    }


public async Task<string> SelectQuery(string tablename, DataGrid dg, DataTable dt)
    {
        Task<bool> task = new Task<bool>(()=>Select(tablename,dt));
        task.Start();
        bool IsComplete = await task;
        if (IsComplete == true)
        {
            dg.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
            return "0";
        }
        else
            return "";

    }

    public bool Select(string tablename, DataTable dt)
    {
        MySqlConnection conn = connection();
        try
        {
            string commandquery = "select SQL_NO_CACHE * from " + tablename+ " ORDER BY ID DESC";
            conn.Open();
            MySqlCommand c = new MySqlCommand("SET ARITHABORT ON", conn);
            MySqlCommand com = new MySqlCommand(commandquery, conn);
            MySqlDataReader adp = com.ExecuteReader();
            //MySqlDataAdapter adp = new MySqlDataAdapter(commandquery,conn);
            dt.Clear();
            //adp.Fill(dt);
            dt.Load(adp);

            return true;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error, MessageBoxResult.OK, MessageBoxOptions.RtlReading);
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

I tried both MySqlDataReader and MySqlDataReader, but nothing changed.
I checked code's line by line,for first time, `MySqlCommand com = new MySqlCommand(commandquery, conn);` takes about 8 seconds, and then less than 1 second,about 500 ms.
For testy table with 10000 rows in first project, all above lines run fast and after finishing, app crash, so the problem is from my application, but I don't know where is the problem and other tables works good!
I checked memory usage,for other table's, usage is good but for 10000 table's memory just increase and app not respond after some second.
Any suggestion to solve this problems?
And Is this faster to use php to get data from DB and and send it to C# app?
I googled many things for my problem and saw many solution but can't solve it.

**UPDATE:**
I realized that my second problem(crashing app) was because of setting `scrollviewer.cancontentscroll` to `false` that increase RAM usage too much.
by not setting this to false, other problem will appears; datagrid lost smooth scrolling!

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**:
I couldn't fix first select query delay.
but for second problem, I made my "Select" method asynchronous and changed loading rows limit to 50 each time, and after scroll reached to 90% of scroll height, next page(next 50 rows) will be loaded and so on.
I think this is the best way because certainly loading huge data cost much RAM and CPU and loading by scrolling is better than making pages button.
If you set `scrollviewer.cancontentscroll` to `false`, RAM usage will increase, so it is better to use a few rows so you can set it to `false` (this is necessary for smooth scrolling).